# How to show the download progress in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to do the download progress in the apps like the image below:
[image]

If I press the download button in the left image then the progress can keep track as the right image. Does anyone know is there have any package or way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) plugin. You can either add `Linear percent indicators` under your download button while downloading or just replace the whole thing with `Circular percent indicators`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using percent_indicator package. On this [link](https://youtu.be/QN-6MNc39Dg), it is already implemented to show download progress using percent_indicator. Though it is for individual list item but you can implement it similar way for button.